# Architecture for a c++ XML-parser with a HTML-reportgenerator

Tags: c++, qt, oop, architecture

I want a program that parses a XML-file, build a structure with the tags I need and finally print a HTML-report using HTML-templates with keywords that get replaced by the data from the XML files.
Since I'm not(yet) really into the OO programming I hoped to get some tips and advices how to structure a program like this.
I thought that two classes should be enough. A parser class and a data class.
the first one to go through the XML-file and report every tag I want to store to a data object which stores all the tags in a hierarchical order. After that I want to call a print function which prints everything as HTML-report.

1. I'm not sure how to report the tags to the data object
2. Could I store the tags in one object which stores a tree of structs or would it be better to store each tag in a separate object?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is C++ a must? You can do this using XSLT, see e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: @Zane I read about XSLT but this time I want to try it with C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem and want to share my architecture.
I made a Class Parser to parse the Elements and report the tags to an HTMLHandler class which has Subclasses like Header, Content and Sub-content. which store the Data and all have write()- methodes to print themselves out.

works fine for me and is quit simple :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention Qt in your question, but as you added it as a tag: there is QtXML, which will give a way to parse and generate XML documents, and will also work for HTML output. XML is typically handled either via DOM or SAX. With DOM, the documents are parsed into a tree structure, and you will work on the tree as your central data element. With SAX, you use callback functions that are called for the different XML elements while parsing the XML input.

There is a lot about DOM and SAX on the internet, Wikipedia is a good starting point. There is also a lot of documentation on QtXML on-line.

Using DOM and/or SAX will give a nice architecture for solving the problem.

Comment: yes I want to use Qt, sorry that I didn't mention it. I'll get started reading what possibilities I get with QtXml to create Html output.

Comment: I couldn't find any support to output HTML. I already used QDom and QXmlStreamReader for small projects. So parsing the XML is not the problem. I hoped to get some advice in how to make the architecture of the application in a way that the components are reusable. for example if I want to change the output datatype someday...

Comment: XHTML (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_xhtml.asp)  is XML-compliant HTML, so you can output this to get an HTML document. Seems you are thininkg of some general-purpose report generator - could you give a simple example what data you anaylse and how a report would look like?